# Adding a line break in curl params

Tags: arrays, curl, line-breaks

I need to add \n or something equivalent to it in the labelled positions .

```
$params = array(
'msg' => 'Hi <line break>, A new account has been created. <line break> Bye',
     .......
);
```

Thanks.

Comment: In what context are you trying to display the message? A web page? An email? A text file?

Comment: It sends this msg using curl via HTTP API to SMS gateway

Comment: It looks like the line break character for SMS is generally `%0A`; it may vary based on which gateway you're using, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the line break character for SMS is generally %0A; it may vary based on which gateway you're using, though.

Comment: Thanks for this! Works great with pushbullet notifications too!